# Как можно получить доступ к базам данных Кинопоиска?

Tags: юридические-аспекты

Мне хотелось бы попользоваться всей базой кинопоиска для коммерческих целей. Для того, чтобы это сделать, мне нужно платить им? И где можно взять бесплатно базу с фильмами?

Comment: вы имеете ввиду описания и спойлеры фильмов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насчет кинопоиска - спросите, как ни странно, на кинопоиске. А насчет базы - вам для каких целей? Если нужна информация о фильмах, то можно парсить википедию на лету.

Comment: хотелось бы уже готовую базу... а есть скрипт чтобы собрать все фильмы с википедии?

Comment: напишите. несложно.